# ¿ossaudiodev no funciona?

Tags: python, python-3.x, audio, sonido, mp3

Tengo un problema: ossaudiodev no me reproduce un archivo de audio,.mp3 ni,.m4a ni uno,.wav.

Mi codigo es el siguiente si alguien  me puede decir el problema muchas gracias:

```
import ossaudiodev as audio
audio.open("audio.mp3","w")
```

el error es el siguiente :(

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/accomp_files/iiec_run/iiec_run.py", line 31, in <module>
    start(fakepyfile,mainpyfile)
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/accomp_files/iiec_run/iiec_run.py", line 30, in start
    exec(open(mainpyfile).read(),  __main__.__dict__)
  File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
OSError: [Errno 25] Not a typewriter: 'audio.mp3'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De la documentación oficial:

**ossaudiodev.open(device, mode)**

Abre un dispositivo de audio y retorne un objeto de dispositivo de audio OSS. Este objeto admite muchos métodos similares a archivos, como read(), write(), and fileno() (aunque existen diferencias sutiles entre la semántica de lectura/escritura convencional de Unix y la de audio OSS dispositivos). También es compatible con varios métodos específicos de audio; vea a continuación la lista completa de métodos.

**device** es el nombre de archivo del dispositivo de audio que se utilizará. Si no se especifica, este módulo primero busca en la variable de entorno AUDIODEV para un dispositivo a usar. Si no se encuentra, vuelve a /dev/dsp.

Como puedes apreciar, la función **no** recibe un archivo.